# Can a space station have its own satellite?

Tags: artificial-satellite

Moon orbits around Earth and space station orbit around the Earth, can a space station have some objects orbit around it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, low Earth orbit satellites can't have their own satellites.

From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere#Further_examples

> An astronaut could not orbit the Space Shuttle (with mass of 104
>   tonnes), where the orbit is 300 km above the Earth, since the Hill
>   sphere of the shuttle is only 120 cm in radius, much smaller than the
>   shuttle itself. A sphere of this size and mass would be denser than
>   lead. **In fact, in any low Earth orbit, a spherical body must be more
>   dense than lead in order to fit inside its own Hill sphere, or else it
>   will be incapable of supporting an orbit.** A spherical geostationary
>   satellite however would only need to be more than 6% of the density of
>   water to support satellites of its own.

Comment: Formation flying is a definite possibility, though.

Comment: If this helps, radius of the ISS' Hill sphere at its [current semi-major axis and mass](http://isslive.com/displays/topoDisplay1.html) is ~ [1.9 m](https://goo.gl/Ytg61h). If it orbited at GEO altitude, this would increase to 11.8 m, which still isn't enough to find a stable orbital inclination around it (essentially around Node 1 orthogonal to station's velocity vector) that doesn't intersect its truss.